# CSS animation not working in firefox keyframe

Tags: html, css, keyframe

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CHK</title>
<style>
@keyframes a1
{
00% {background-color:red;}
20% {background-image:url(1.jpg);}
50% {background-color:orange;}
70% {background-color:silver;}
98% {background-color:blue;}
100% {background-color:red;}
}
#ida
{
width:200px;
height:200px;
animation-name:a1;
animation-duration:8s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ida">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i am using keyframes this is working fine in chrome but in firefox the image i have used is not being displayed idk what is the reason.... pls take a look thx..

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit? What do you _want_ to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/o3wz9wb6/) It works in Firefox for me

Comment: Works for me too (Mac 10.10.3 with FF 39.0 and FF Developer Edition 41.0a2)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't support animatable `background-image`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Comment: is there some other way i can make this work on firefox and other browser too ... i just wanna make a simple slide of some images

Comment: I found this code and it's using only CSS [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hajmd/) , but there's also plenty of those using jQuery you can find all over the web.